# AMD Radeon HD 5450 GPU Drivers? (16.04)

Tags: 16.04, gpu, gpu-driver

- I have a Radeon HD 5450 GPU
- It has support to up to 15.04
- I have Ubuntu 16.04

Will 15.04 drivers work for me? Or are there some drivers for 16.04?

Later Addon: i just want to play dota, it will not show up, on the dota thread, they said that i need drivers..

Comment: No, 15.04 drivers will not work on 16.04. HD5450 will just work in 16.04, with not tinkering required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, on 16.04 the `fglrx` drivers became deprecated.

You'll need to use the open-source `amdgpu` driver instead.

From the release notes:

> **fglrx**
>
> The fglrx driver is now deprecated in 16.04, and we recommend its open
>   source alternatives (radeon and amdgpu). AMD put a lot of work into
>   the drivers, and we backported kernel code from Linux 4.5 to provide a
>   better experience.
>
> When upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 from a previous release, both the fglrx
>   driver and the xorg.conf will be removed, so that the system is set to
>   use either the amdgpu driver or the radeon driver (depending on the
>   available hardware).

Comment: Why unfortunately? Not that fglrx was so great or anything.

Comment: @mikewhatever - The amdgpu driver has worse performance, so I hear.

Answer (score 1):

AMD didn't offer catalyst driver for 16.04 Ubuntu.
It will work with amdgpu, though i recommend you upgrade the kernel to 4.6 stable which has improved the driver significantly.

If you're more of a gamer, I'd stick to 15.10

Comment: *i edited the original q, maybe it is better to win-boot.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I was on Ubuntu 16.04 and upgraded to 18.04 and the Radeon card is working again, and the CAD software too.

So 18.04's support for Radeon's is much better!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/836254)

Comment: @stumblebee Support for fglrx drivers was dropped in 16.04 and left many Radeon graphics card users in the lurch. The gist of this answer is that support for Radeon cards has improved in 18.04, so my review is "Looks OK".